# Open Window on same screen and centered

Tags: javascript, popup, window, prototypejs

Using the following code, the window opens up in different locations, never centered, depending on which screen you open it on. I am having this problem using Internet Explorer 9 and my screen has a resolution of 1920x1080.

What I need is for the window to open, centered, on the screen I opened it on. I have searched stackoverflow and haven't found anything that works for me.

```
self.window.open(
    '/form.php?id=' + $iFormID +
    '&cboActivePatient=' + $iSkey +
    '&sForm=' + $sForm +
    '&iFormNum=' + $iFormNum,
    $sForm,
    'channelmode=yes, toolbar=yes, ' +
    'location=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, fullscreen=no, status=yes');
```

I have already tried using:

```
var tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
var tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;

'location=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, fullscreen=no, ' +
                'status=yes, left='+tempX+', top='+tempY+'');
```

But that does not work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not something you can control in general, across different browsers and different operating systems etc. You can't even be sure that `window.open()` will open a separate browser window (as opposed to a new tab).

Comment: What do you mean by "same screen". However, the window will never be centered somewhere when you specify left and top, but not width and height.

Comment: Same screen as in I have 2 monitors and I would like the window to open on the monitor that I clicked in, not the primary monitor. I don't necessarily need it centered anymore as it opening at the top left is fine.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the screen.width and screen.height to get the screen size of the client computer, and using that to calculate the appropriate values for the top and left [specs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) something like this:

```
URL = 'http://nickbriz.com'
w = 500;
h = 200;
t = (screen.height/2) - h/2;
l = (screen.width/2) - w/2;  

window.open(URL,'someName','width='+w+',height='+h+',top='+t+',left='+l+'')​;​
```

here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pRA9B/